# Are there performance considerations when refactoring members of a class into a struct container?

Tags: c#, performance, memory-management, refactoring

Lets say I have several classes like these:

```
class MyClassA {
    public List<string> UpData;
    public List<string> DownData;
    public List<string> LeftData;
    public List<string> RightData;
}

class MyClassB {
    public List<string> UpData;
    public List<string> DownData;
    public List<string> LeftData;
    public List<string> RightData;
}
```

I'd like to refactor them so I can add some conveniences (like an Enumerator, or having some functions that let me pick a specific member):

```
struct DirectionMap {
    public List<string> Up;
    public List<string> Down;
    public List<string> Left;
    public List<string> Right;
    //... various helper functions ...
}

class MyClassA {
    public DirectionMap Data;
}

class MyClassB {
    public DirectionMap Data;
}
```

However, my application is very memory intensive, and I have millions of instances of these, so I need to keep memory usage and garbage collection in mind.  I also have to mutate these objects as often as possible, so speed is important too.  Is there any performance overhead to doing this?

If I understand correctly, if `DirectionMap` were a class, it would use a bit more memory to store the pointer to it, and touch the heap an extra time, right?  But is it free as a struct?

I understand that mutable objects in structs can cause mistakes, but I don't plan on ever passing `Data` around, just the string lists it contains, which are reference values.

Comment: you have a list of strings, which would obviously go into the heap, don't they?

Comment: Yes, but the `DirectionMap` itself doesn't, right? I just wanted to know if there's anything else I'm missing.

Comment: Could you post one helper method of the `DirectionMap` struct as an example?

Comment: For example, I could implement `IEnumerable<List<string>>` with basically `GetEnumerator() { yield return UpData; yield return DownData; yield return LeftData; yield return RightData; }`, so I can iterate over the values.

Comment: Or I could have a function take in a `Direction` enum and return the desired member.

Comment: Your structs are still allocated on heap. Also if you pass struct as parameters, the compiler creates defensive copy which could be a drawback affecting performance. Performance wise maybe benchmark test your solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first rule when talking about performance is to profile the code, even experienced developers may be surprised at what things take time.

I would expect the memory usage and performance to be identical if you put things in a struct vs directly in a class. The memory layout should be similar or identical.

I would not recommend mutating the struct unless you are very careful. I.e. replacing the contents of the Up-list would be fine, but replacing the Up-list with a new list could cause issues. See [Why mutating structs are evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441309/why-are-mutable-structs-evil).

If you implement interfaces for your struct you need to be aware of boxing. If you implement `IEnumerable<List<string>>` and use any linq method this would cause the struct to be [boxed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing), not ideal for performance. This should be possible to avoid by using generic constraints. You might also want to use a readonly struct and the  and the [in parameter modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/in-parameter-modifier) to avoid copies . For example :

```
public static void MyMethod<T, U>(in T value) where T : struct, IEnumerable<U>
{
        // do something
}
```

Comment: I don't thing that the OP intends to mutate the structs themselves. Their intention is to mutate the objects that are stored in the structs. Your suggestion of making the structs [`readonly`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/write-safe-efficient-code#declare-readonly-structs-for-immutable-value-types) is a great suggestion IMHO, in order to enforce these intentions.

Comment: Thanks. Does using `foreach` on an `IEnumerable`cause boxing?  Also, is there a way to use `readonly` on a generic struct, like if I had `DirectionMap<T>` with `List<T> Up;` instead?  The compiler says I need Ts to be readonly, but I don't see a way to constrain it.

Comment: using foreach should not cause boxing as far as I know. Using generics in a readonly struct should be fine, but all fields need to be marked as readonly.